# Рациональное использование вложенных div-блоков

Tags: html, вёрстка

Существуют ли какие-нибудь практики по верстке сайтов, определяющие необходимый уровень вложенности div-блоков. К примеру, мне необходимо сверстать шапку сайта, сейчас я бы сделал так:

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <span>Logo text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="searh-input></div>
            <div class="search-button">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Класс `container` использую для обёртывания нескольких блоков, но существует класс `wrapper`, который по советам должен использоваться для обёртывания одного элемента. Нужна ли здесь такая вложенность div блоков? Просто помню, что так необходимо делать, чтобы далее не было каких-то проблем, но не могу найти статью, где об этом рассказывается. Или может быть не стоит заморачиваться и всё это можно сделать совсем по другому и намного проще?

Comment: Вот когда проблемы будут, тогда и оборачивайте

Comment: Сделать можно разными способами, всё зависит от задачи. При том что вложенность блоков может быть любой.